# How to get part of a unique part of a string by doing partial string match

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to figure out a way to get part of a string by providing common sting match. The code is set up at:
http://jsfiddle.net/rexonms/0s7cgxku/

```
Javascript
----------

findIds(txt);

var ids = [];
var txt = "And all I need is the fan-page-id-xx and also the fan-page-id-yy but not fan-page."


function findIds(txt){

   var word = txt.match(/fan-page-id/m); //how do I get the ids (xx, yy) from here?
   var id = 'x';
   ids.push(id);
   console.log(ids)
}
```

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/uQ2nC7/1 Is it what you were looking for?

Comment: @PM77-1 yep. That's awesome. That's a kick ass way to do it :)

Comment: By using the regex suggested by @PM77-1, you can get all the xx and yy value in ids by using looping the match value http://jsfiddle.net/zeskysee/hqcmkx0v/

Comment: @Zesky - Yes, this seems to be [the way](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/432493/how-do-you-access-the-matched-groups-in-a-javascript-regular-expression) to do it.